# UIPickerView delegate method titleForRow not executing correctly?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Guys i am facing an issue while implementing delegate method for UIPickerview. Description of the problem is, i want to have 3 components in pickerview and each component having different number of rows. The code for this is as follows

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 3;

}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component

{   
    NSInteger rows;
    if (0 == component)
        rows = 5;
    else if (1 == component)
        rows = 10;
    else
        rows = 15;

    NSLog(@"Number of rows returned for component %d are rows %d",component, rows);
    return rows;
}
```

Following this i am implementing "titleForRow" delegate method code for which is as follows:

```
#pragma -mark UIPIckerView Delegate Methods
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        //NSString *temp;


        //temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row]];
    if (0 == component)
    {
    NSLog(@"String returned is %@ for row %d for component %d", [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row], row, component);
    return [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if
        (1 == component){
        NSLog(@"String returned is %@ for row %d for component %d", [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row], row, component);
    return [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"String returned is %@ for row %d for component %d", [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row], row, component);
    return [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row];
    }
        //return temp;
        //  return [self.pocModelData.arrayOfDistricts objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

This method on execution is returning only 3 rows for each component, as shown by following statements

```
2013-05-18 02:00:40.743 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 0 are rows 5
2013-05-18 02:00:41.221 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 1 are rows 10
2013-05-18 02:00:41.696 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 2 are rows 15
2013-05-18 02:00:42.035 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 0 are rows 5
2013-05-18 02:00:43.761 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 1 for row 0 for component 0
2013-05-18 02:00:44.687 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 2 for row 1 for component 0
2013-05-18 02:00:45.048 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 3 for row 2 for component 0
2013-05-18 02:00:45.544 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 1 are rows 10
2013-05-18 02:00:46.131 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 1 for row 0 for component 1
2013-05-18 02:00:46.620 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 2 for row 1 for component 1
2013-05-18 02:00:47.380 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 3 for row 2 for component 1
2013-05-18 02:00:47.772 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] Number of rows returned for component 2 are rows 15
2013-05-18 02:00:48.543 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 1 for row 0 for component 2
2013-05-18 02:00:48.915 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 2 for row 1 for component 2
2013-05-18 02:00:49.461 PopOverControllerExample[8228:c07] String returned is 3 for row 2 for component 2
```

I am not able to comprehend as to why its executing only 3 times for each component?
I am populating the rows with set of data, so data source is common for all of them. What is the issue here, i am not able to grasp and m stuck for some time now? Any guidance is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only queries the values that are visible. With row 0 at the center of the spinner, you have 3 rows visible. Once you spin it will query the other values.

Comment: thnks @mvds, but can you elaborate a bit more? Correct me if i am wrong, but do u mean, that its returning 3 values only cause, there are only 3 rows visible?

Comment: @experimentalist yes, as more values need to be displayed, they are requested. Just spin the picker and you will see that other values are requested.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation..it helped me in resolving my issue!!:)

Comment: sorry took some time to update and acknowledge that ur explanation solved my query. kinda of new to posting questions, so still a noob